# Delete cell value with VLOOKUP VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cell, vlookup

I am trying to delete a cell value based on a VLOOKUP search but it's throwing me error " method range of object _global failed 1004 " The error appears when I am trying to delete the username.

```
Private Sub Delete_Click()
Dim sht As String
Dim username as String

'Selects the worksheet based on combobox value.
sht = Me.Combobox1.Value
'Use a VLOOKUP to Search for the username on a worksheet previously selected on
'sht variable. 
username = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.textbox1.Value,
 Worksheets(sht).Range("A:F"), 1, 
False)
'Delete the username found on the VLOOKUP
Range(username).Clear
```

Comment: `Vlookup` returns the value of the cell, not the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your syntax. Please try this code. I think it implements your idea.

```
Private Sub Delete_Click()

    Dim Sht             As Worksheet
    Dim UserName        As String
    Dim R               As Long
    
    ' Sets the worksheet based on Combobox value.
    Set Sht = Worksheets(Me.Combobox1.Value)
    UserName = Me.TextBox1.Value

    ' Use MATCH to Search for the username on worksheet Sht
    On Error Resume Next
    R = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match( _
                    UserName, Sht.Columns("A"), 0)
    If Err Then
        MsgBox """" & UserName & """ wasn't found."
    Else
        'Delete the username found by the MATCH function
        Sht.Cells(R, "A").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand your code really good and now I am seeing what I missed. I just don't know why I am having the error code "Object Required" on the ` Set Sht = Me.Combobox1.Value`

Comment: That's definitely not your fault, but mine. I have modified my reply and apologize for the inconvenience caused. The ComboBox holds the name of the sheet, of course, not the sheet itself. Note that the line will still fail if the sheet doesn't exist by exactly the given name (not case-sensitive) in the same workbook as the code.

Comment: You're awesome! It works!! Thanks so much for your help!